# How to compare each line of a text File? java

Tags: java, text, compare, lines, lowercase

I have a text file with content like, with 792 lines:

```
der 17788648
und 14355959
die 10939606
Die 10480597
```

Now I want to compare if  "Die" and "die" are equal in lowercase. 
So if two Strings in lowerCase are equal, copy the word into a new text file in lowerCase and sum the values.

Expected output:

```
der 17788648
und 14355959
die 114420203
```

I have that so far:

```
    try {
        BufferedReader bk = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        bk = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("outagain.txt"));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outagain5.txt"));

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String s = "";
        while (s != null) {
            s = bk.readLine();
            list.add(s);
        }


        for (int k = 0; k < 793; k++) {
            String u = bk.readLine();
            if (list.contains(u.toLowerCase())) {

                //sum values?

            } else {
                bw.write(u + "\n");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list.size());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e);
    }
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi how can I make it to compare each line? I mean: I want to read the first line and compare it to all others in lowerCase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a HashMap to keep track of the unique fields. Before you do a put, do a get to see if the value is already there. If it is, sum the old value with the new one and put it in again (this replaces the old line having same key)

```
package com.foundations.framework.concurrency;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FileSummarizer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Long> rows = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        String key = tokens[0].toLowerCase();
        Long current = Long.parseLong(tokens[1]);

        Long previous = rows.get(key);
        if(previous != null){
          current += previous;
        }
        rows.put(key, current);
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      try {
        reader.close();
        Iterator<String> iterator = rows.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String key = iterator.next().toString();
          String value = rows.get(key).toString();

          System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting error   at `Long current = Long.parseLong(tokens[1]);` with ArrayOutOfBounds exception.. any Idea why?

Comment: your split isn;t working ... check your file, make sure second token is always a number...don't  have empty lines in your file

Comment: I changed the parameter in the split() Method and now it's working! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `list.add(s);`, use `list.add(s.toLowerCase());`. Right now your code is comparing lines of indeterminate case to lower-cased lines.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, the best approach to standard problems like reading files, comparing, grouping, collecting is to use the streams api, since it is much more concise to do that in that way. At least when the files is only a few KB, then there will be no problems with that.
Something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> nameSumMap = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))
            .map(x -> x.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x[0].toLowerCase(),
                    Collectors.summingInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(x[1]))
            ));
```

First, you can read the file with `Files.lines()`, which returns a `Stream<String>`, than you can split the strings into a `Stream<String[]>`, 
finally you can use the `groupingBy()` and `summingInt()`  functions to group by the first element of the array and sum by the second one.

If you don't want to use the stream API, you can also create a `HashMap` und do your summing manually in the loop.

Comment: I provided an example for OP using your second approach, but I must say, the first approach is damn nice :)

Answer (score 0):

The String class has an equalIgnoreCase method which you can use to compare two strings irrespective of case. so:

```
String var1 = "Die";
String var2 = "die";

System.out.println(var1.equalsIgnoreCase(var2));
```

Would print TRUE.

Comment: But how can I compare eachLine from with all others file? The equals Method is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want to know how you can get the prefix from the file, compare it, get the value behind it and sum them up for each prefix. Is that about right?

You could use regular expressions to get the prefixes and values seperately. Then you can sum up all values with the same prefix and write them to the file for each one.

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, this links could help you:

[Regex on tutorialpoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

[Regex on vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

For additional tutorials just scan google for "java regex" or similar tags.

If you do not want to differ between upper- and lowercase strings, just convert them all to lower/upper before comparing them as @spork explained already.